# How to display uploaded and uploading files using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to upload the files to server and show them in the list using react and typescript.

**what i am trying to do?**

i have two sections first list and second list. and a upload button to upload files like in below picture.

[image]

when user selects files and clicks upload button, the files that have been selected by user will be displayed and once upload starts progress bar will be shown for the file that is being uploading (only one file uploaded at a time). once the file is uploaded the file will be removed from the files state and  attachments state will fetch uploaded files from server.

below is my code,

```
function List() {
    const [file, setFile] = React.useState({ name: null });
    const [files, setFiles] = React.useState([]);
    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = React.useState(false);
    const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = React.useState(0);
    const fileRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [getAttachmentUploadUrl] = useLazyQuery(GET_UPLOAD_URL, {
        onCompleted: (data: any) => uploadFile(data.getAttachmentUploadUrl),
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        if (files && files[0]) {
            if (files[0].size > 10000) {
                toast.error('File size limit');
                setFiles(files.slice(1));
            } else {
                setFile(files[0]);
                getAttachmentUploadUrl();
            }
        }
    }, [files, setFile, setFiles, getAttachmentUploadUrl]);


   const uploadFile = async (data: AttachmentUrlResponse) => {
       try {
           setIsUploading(true);

           await axios.put(data.uploadUrl, file, {
               onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: any) =>
               setUploadProgress(
                   Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
               ),
           });

           const input: AttachmentCreateInput = {
               uploadId: data.uploadId,
               section: activeTab, //activeTab is the variable telling which 
    // tab has been selected by user first list or second list
    filename: file.name,
  };
           await addAttachement({
               variables: { input },
           });

           await refetchAttachment();

           setIsUploading(false);
           setUploadProgress(0);
           setFile({ name: null });
           setFiles(files.slice(1));
       } catch (e) {
           toast.error('File upload failed');
       }
   };


   const handleFilesDrop = (event: any) => {
       const { files } = event.type === 'drop' ? event.dataTransfer : event.target;
       if (files && files.length > 0) {
           handleUploadedFile(files);
       }
   };

   const handleUploadedFile = async (files: any) => {
       setFiles(Object.values(files)); 
   };

   const uploadClickHandler = () => {
       if (fileRef.current) fileRef.current.click();
   };

   const handleFileChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
       event.persist();
       event.preventDefault();

       const { files } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
       if (files && !isUploading) handleUploadedFile(files);
   };

   const { data: attachments, refetch: refetchattachments } = useQuery(
       LIST_ATTACHMENTS
   );


   return (
       <>
           <Container>
               <Tab>
                   <span>First list</span>
               </Tab>
               <Tab>
                   <span>Second list</span>
               </Tab>
               <FileListContainer>
                   {isUploading && files && //this shows files that is to be
                       // uploaded yet

                       files.map((file, index) => (
                           <span>{file.name}</span>
                               {index=== 0 && <ProgressBar>}
                       )
                   }
                   {attachments && attachments.data.filter( //this has files 
                       // that is uploaded and retrieved from server
                       (attachment: Attachment) =>
                           attachment.section === activeTab
                       )
                       .map((attachment,index) => (
                           <span>{attachment.filename}</span>
                       )
                   }
               </FileListContainer>
               <FileUpload onClick={handleFileChange}/>
           </Container>
       </>
   );
}
```

The above code works fine. but the problem is since the state files has initial files selected by user and files not uploaded and attachments has uploaded files and both will display in the FileListContainer there is some blinking seen in the file list UI that is when one file upload done the other files that are yet to be uploaded are not seen for a moment.

so i was thinking to recode this logic to read and display files from single array rather than two now from files and attachments. but i am not sure how to go about it. i am new to programming especially these kind of ones.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: `when one file upload done the other files that are yet to be uploaded are not seen for a moment.` -> so when a file upload gets done, the files on the upload queue (the files that are not get uploaded yet) are not shown for a sec? or only the file that is uploaded won't show for a sec?

Comment: the files on the upload queue (the files that are not get uploaded yet) are not shown for a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when a file upload gets done, the files on the upload queue are not shown for a sec.

That's because you set the `isUploading` to `false` on uploadDone:

```
  setIsUploading(false);
  setUploadProgress(0);
```

But you're showing the files on the queue only when `isUploading` is true.

```
{isUploading && files && files.map(...)}
```

So this prevent the files to be rendered between `uploadDone` and `startNextFileUpload` duration.
So you can just remove the `isUploading` condition on render, like this:

```
{files && files.map(...)}
```

Comment: thanks a ton for your answer. it saved my day :) i was working on this for almost 4 hours now. so in my code isuploading state can be removed completely right?

Comment: @someuser2491 No problem. yes i think so, because `isuploading` in your code is equlivant to `files != null` or `if(files)`. happy codding .